# Checking for duplicates from a SharePoint input form, client side javascript

Tags: javascript

Folks, I have a custom button on SharePoint form with an `onClick` event that is as follows:

```
onclick="if (!itemDuplicated()){ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirectsource')}; window.alert('Item updated.') ; window.close();"
```

The script to handle the click event is as follows:

```
                function itemDuplicated(){


                        var field1 = document.getElementById(&quot;ctl00_m_g_7d2eac47_1ef1_4ab4_96b7_38089fea54a1_ff21_ctl00_ctl00_TextField&quot;).value;

                    var siteUrl = &apos;http://myurl&apos;;

                    var clientContext =  new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

                    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(&quot;RFC Field Grouping (kerry test of concept)&quot;);

                    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
                    camlQuery.set_viewXml(&apos;<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='field1'/><Value Type='Text'>&apos; + field1 + &apos;</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>&apos;);

                    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);                          

                    clientContext.load(collListItem, &apos;Include(Title)&apos;);

                    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onListItemsLoadSuccess),Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));

                }  //end function
```

in the `this.onListItemsLoadSuccess` function I am easily able to get the value I need from the caml query but because it is running `Async` it never gets considered and the itemDuplicated function always returns false.

I have read a lot about this and how it's a difficult thing to accomplish, making asynchronous calls synchronous (not recommended) and using callbacks, etc

I have tried a bunch of different things to no avail.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the onclick event to just call your function

```
onclick="itemDuplicated()"
```

Then rewrite the onListItemsLoadSuccess function to handle your if statement

```
function onListItemsLoadSuccess()
{
   //Check if duplicated and then run code if we have duplicate
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer.  This is a great suggestion and one I had explored initially.  However, the problem I ran into was trying to submit the form with javascrpt.  I.e.  If no duplicates were found, then I want to simply submit the form.

Plugging GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirectsource') into the javascript didn't work...nor did the standard document.forms[0].submit() or document.getElementByID("aspnetForm).submit()

This is such a simple thing but yet it is so difficult to accomplish.

Any suggestion?  Thanks again.

Comment: ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent probably goes out of scope depending on how you wire the async callback. Try storing the function ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent in a variable you can reach from onListItemsLoadSuccess() function.

If you just want to try it out and play ugly you can do:

    window["myfunc"] = ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent;

And then call it with:

    window.myfunc('__commit;__redirectsource')